# Eclipse 2022-06 does not show outline of a pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, pom.xml, outline

Eclipse 2022-06-ee does not show the outline of a pom.xml anymore:

[image]

Eclipse 2021-09-ee showed it (the same project, the same file):

[image]

What can I do that the outline is shown again in eclipse 2022-06?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this either in Eclipse 2022-06 nor in 2022-09RC1. Is this a fresh installation without additional plugins?

Comment: It's a fresh 'installation' (just unpacking the zip) on a windows 10 machine. There are some plugins, but basically the same as in the 2021-09 version (Environment Variable, Bash Editor, Batch Editor, Docker Tooling, SonarLint, Jenkins Editor). Today I switched from the embedded runtime (vm arg in eclipse.ini) to a OpenJDK-17. Still the same effect.

Comment: Note that - when starting with 2022-06 - I also copied the workspace from 2021-09.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a fresh installation without any additional plugin and a fresh workspace?

Comment: I can confirm that on a fresh installation (unzipping eclipse-jee-2022-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip)  and a fresh workspace the problem does not occur (when opening the same maven project). But when opening the copied workspace with the fresh 2022-06 installation the problem remains. It seems it has to do with the copied workspace, since opening the fresh workspace with the other eclipse installation (with the plugins) does not show the problem.

Comment: Did you copy the workspace to a different location? Do not move an existing workspace. Use the old workspace with a new Eclipse or use a new workspace into which you import the existing projects instead.

Comment: Thanks for your time and recommendations. But using a new workspace is not an option. There are so many little things configured (colors, shortcuts, layout, etc). I did this since years: When using a new eclipse, I just copied the old workspace (I mean the folder with the .metadata subfolder, not the project sources) into a new folder, opened it with the new eclipse version and upgraded it.

Comment: Moving or deleting the `.metadata` folder can cause issues (since it also contains absolute paths). You can use the same workspace with different versions of Eclipse (only in raw cases there might be small glitches when using a workspace created with a newer version of Eclipse) and you can export/import the preferences. There are also the preference recorder which provides even more possibilities for sharing preferences between installations.

Comment: I second @howlger on preference import. Export all preferences from the old eclipse, import into the new one.  NEVER copy workspaces.

Comment: Maybe I ill give it another try with the actual version.  Some years ago (~4 +) the preferences export/import was not at all satisfying. Many important configurations were not covered. "You can use the same workspace with different versions of Eclipse": no, you cannot. once opened (and upgraded) with newer version, the ws cannot be opened anymore with elder version.

Comment: Just exported the prefs from 2021-09 and imported them into a new ws in 2022-06: The original problem (no outline shown from pom editor) ist still present! -> Your suggestion does not solve my problem. Only if I open the project in a brand new workspace (without any modifications) the outline of the pom editor is shown. (BTW: The export/import of prefs does not even cover the workbench layouts. Good idea, but very poor realization).

Comment: When opening a workspace created with a newer version of Eclipse, you will get a warning and you can choose to proceed. A moved workspace cannot be healed by importing preferences. It is still unclear to me for what purpose you need a duplicate of your workspace. _File > Switch Workspace_ offers the option to copy also the workbench layout. Again, I cannot reproduce your issue. Your issue seems to be caused by moving the workspace which was a mistake you made.